# upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 shows failure kernel load errors

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I hit upgrade, then I waited for packages to be downloaded. I had to go to slep then I found this message, but, I was doing some reasearch and someone said this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943 solution works. I have not tried it since I had to go to work, but, does anybody know if that solution will apply for 16.04 still. or if is there another workaround?

[image]

Comment: Is 16.06 a mistake? Because there is no version called that.

Comment: do you mean 16.04?

Comment: It will work with no problem.

Comment: I will be back home in about 9 hours, so I will tell you how'd go

Comment: hey. what should I do after I do all this? should I just restart?. I have to say that I did not use any cd or dvd or usb I just upgraded as it wqs offerded by the software update center

Comment: I just get a black screen that says no boot option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47115/discussion-between-mark-yisri-and-ken-sandoval).

Comment: I do not have windows installed. I actually had 14.04 installed, and I daily was receiving the little message of "your software is up to date but you are still using 14.04. you can upgrade to 16.06. " and there were two buttons. Upgrade an OK. So, I decided the night I started the thread to begin upgrade. I had made backups of everything anyway, like videos and personal pictures on Amazon Cloud Drive, so I am not really worried about data loss.

Comment: If I have to start from scratch I will do it, however,
it is funny because now the computer when I boot up, and press ctrl atl F2, I get the message saying "Welcome to Ubuntu 16.06" and bla bla blah. "

Comment: After the steps I followed on the link I provided where you confirmed they still work, I tried that and it seem to partiall have worked. so, in other workds it is like it actually upgraded, however,
I have no graphical environment.  when I go back to "graphical " by hitting ctrl alt F7, I get the splash login screen, I login, and it still says "14.04 on the lower corner, but it just gets stuck, I do not even get a little menu at the top for copmuter settings and nothing appears.

Comment: When I am in terminal mode, I to lsd_release and it says 16.04
I go on my home directory and I can see all my fidercorites and everything is there (whitch is a good thing. everything is fine.
I do sudo dpkg --configure -a and it works, then I do sudo apt-get dist upgrade, and it workds, then I do sudo apt/get -f install
and all that works,

Comment: then I do sudo shutdown to restart or just shutdown and it returns a black screen that says "no boot option" press f1 to retry, press f2 to start diagnostics press f5 to set up whatever.

Comment: I am a little sad honestly, but possibly tomorrow that I am off, I am going to have to go purchase a couple of dvd empty discs to burn a 16.04 ISO an use it to boot from it, do you think it will work without loosing all my data? or it will?
as clarification, I have said before that I backed up personal files on Amazon cloud drive, but, all my study files, pdf books, Cisco networking, Linux PDF files, web development course videos and all my recordings are still there.

Comment: something interesting is that I had been making "backups" on the ubuntu back up utility , but I honestly have never known where that goes. But like I said, If I have to start from scratch I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here  you can follow how I managed to do the upgrade: https://www.udemy.com/shell-scripting-linux/learn/v4/questions/1713182
 At the end. I had to create a taball and upload it to my AWS s3 Bucket called [Backup. I used, command line tools by AWS aws s3 cp s3://BuCKET-,. Then, I finally burned the dvd using CLI commands, and didi upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off **secure boot** in your **BIOS** to solve your kernel load failures. Cheers, Al