# How to copy files from Shell CLI into USB or CD

Tags: upgrade, backup, usb-drive, cd

I have been trying to resolve an issue [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943) where my upgrade failed.

I just want to know it is possible and what anybody recommends. I have an idea. I would like to download ISO image from [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=16.04.1&architecture=amd64), and burn it into cd with these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning#Burning_a_CD_or_DVD_using_Command_Line_tools).

I have some questions. Can I then copy all my files into an external USB or cd for backup, or would I be able to get all my data files restored?

If I can copy data to CD, how should I do it? 
Then how should I begin the upgrade or fresh clean process after I burned the ISO image into DVD

Comment: When you reference "all my files", do you mean personal files or system files or both? Is this from an existing OS? Or do you mean the iso files? Please re-word and be a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: Sure, I actually would like to share as well how it all started: http://askubuntu.com/questions/839183/upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-shows-failure-kernel-load-errors

Answer (score 0):

Once you've booted off the live media you have created you should be able to [mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20680/what-does-it-mean-to-mount-something) a target USB device as well as your source partition(s) and copy the data you require over to the target device (your forum post indicates that you already have a backup).

After you have copied all your required data you can simply [install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) as normal.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek I forgot to add my original thread of how everything started.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/839183/upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-shows-failure-kernel-load-errors

Comment: Wow. Did you by any chance http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077#528077 prior to upgrade?

Comment: :-( no I did not. I thought it would work with just clicking on "uprgade now" because I trusted on this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: However, I am still at work and I am getting ready to purchase a little DVD Disc. I am going to go to a library or grocery store to get one, so maybe I will spend all night on this. I am already setting my mind to the fact that I am going to have to do complete fresh clean install, but, my only issue is that I had some important files I have been working for months, and supposedly, the "backup" Graphic interface tool was making those backups, I just don't know where they all go ; -(